# vertically displayed jquery buttonset

Tags: jquery-ui

i'm using the jquery ui button, is it possible to display the radio button vertically?it seems to default to horizontal.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

many thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wrote a short plugin that implement vertical buttonset for radio buttons and checkboxes with jquery ui.

#### 1. jQuery Plugin

```
(function( $ ){
//plugin buttonset vertical
$.fn.buttonsetv = function() {
  $(':radio, :checkbox', this).wrap('<div style="margin: 1px"/>');
  $(this).buttonset();
  $('label:first', this).removeClass('ui-corner-left').addClass('ui-corner-top');
  $('label:last', this).removeClass('ui-corner-right').addClass('ui-corner-bottom');
  var maxWidth = 0; // max witdh
  $('label', this).each(function(index){
     var labelWidth = $(this).width();
     if (labelWidth > maxWidth ) maxWidth = labelWidth ; 
  })
  $('label', this).each(function(index){
    $(this).width(maxWidth);
  })
};
})( jQuery );
```

#### 2. Sample markup

```
<h2> Radio Buttonset </h2>
<div id="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1"/><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2"/><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3"/><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
<h2> Checkbox Buttonset </h2>
<div id="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check" value="1"/><label for="check1">Choice 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check" value="2"/><label for="check2">Choice 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check" value="3"/><label for="check3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
```

#### 3. Plugin Usage

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //call plugin 
    $("#radio").buttonsetv();
    $("#checkbox").buttonsetv();
});
```

[Here the plugin and example code](https://gist.github.com/760885)

I hope this can help you :)

Comment: Please post the code next time, instead of a simple link. Links are good, but they might go down or deleted altogether at a later time. Thus, leaving the future people in need of the solution without a solution.

Comment: Note: The difference between this answer and Joshua's answer, below, is that the formatting is better in this answer (the widths of all the buttons are the same in this answer, but can vary in the other answer, which doesn't look good for vertical buttons).

Answer (score 4):

Place the individual buttons in their own div tags.

Credit to leacar21 from: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-vertical-radio-button-set

`<div id="someSet">
 <div><input type="radio" id="button1"... ></div>
 <div><input type="radio" id="button2"... ></div>
 <div><input type="radio" id="button3"... ></div>
</div>`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I see that the radio buttons have been properly assigned their `ui-buttonset` class from jQuery UI upon the call to `$("...").buttonset()`, but they just appear as normal radio buttons.

Comment: ... turns out I am running into a known conflict between Bootstrap and jQuery UI.  See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6094.  The solution: add `if($.fn.button.noConflict) { $.fn.btn = $.fn.button.noConflict(); }` prior to creating the buttonset.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in way to do this...not at the moment anyway.  The markup and styling is built around a horizontal set.