# How to get vertical radio buttons with jQuery 1.11+?

Tags: jquery

I would like to get vertical radio buttonsets like in [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098054/vertically-displayed-jquery-buttonset). Unfortunatelly, this solution doesn't work for me in the newest (1.11.0) version of jQuery. (Tested on my site and jsFiddle with 1.11.0)

If I try to implement that code into my website, other UI elements, like the slider, won't properly load then.

**Is there a way to fix that code or are there other solutions for vertical radio buttonsets?**

---

Eat code! ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h763Q/1/))

```
<h2> Radio Buttonset </h2>
<div id="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1"/><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2"/><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3"/><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
<h2> Checkbox Buttonset </h2>
<div id="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check" value="1"/><label for="check1">Choice 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check" value="2"/><label for="check2">Choice 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check" value="3"/><label for="check3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
```

---

```
(function( $ ){
//plugin buttonset vertical
$.fn.buttonsetv = function() {
  $(':radio, :checkbox', this).wrap('<div style="margin: 1px"/>');
  $(this).buttonset();
  $('label:first', this).removeClass('ui-corner-left').addClass('ui-corner-top');
  $('label:last', this).removeClass('ui-corner-right').addClass('ui-corner-bottom');
  mw = 0; // max witdh
  $('label', this).each(function(index){
     w = $(this).width();
     if (w > mw) mw = w; 
  })
  $('label', this).each(function(index){
    $(this).width(mw);
  })
};
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function(){
    //call plugin 
    $("#radio").buttonsetv();
    $("#checkbox").buttonsetv();
});
```

---

---

---

For example, I try to initialize these vertical radios in another jQuery-accordion. I have some HTML, then inside this accordion I placed the slider and the horizontal radio buttonsets.

After that HTML I place the JavaScript to create the slider and radios. The slider initializes well, the radios remain standard radio buttons.

after my HTML

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-anzteil" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 4,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#anzteil" ).val( "" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#anzteil" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-anzteil" ).slider( "value" ) );
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    //call plugin 
    $("#radio").buttonsetv();
    $("#checkbox").buttonsetv();
});
```

And that's how it looks then:

[image]

For being complete, my :

```
<link href="jQuery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/open2014.css" type="text/css"> <!-- only references to body and table font styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery/horizontal-plugin.js"></script> <!-- the code block with the horizontal script in it -->
```

Comment: Please add your code here to further analyse your problem. There is no reason at all for that code not to work with the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, added! Also example on jsFiddle where it'll not work with 1.11.0. If you need anything else, please tell me!

Comment: Your fiddle is missing any reference to the jQuery UI script & stylesheet. With those references added, it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/h763Q/3/

Comment: Oh, i added your references to my site, too, but no changes. I edited the question to be more specific, direct code examples also added.

Comment: Plus: When I initialize the radios BEFORE the slider, the slider won't load, too. Am I an Idiot?

Comment: @Trollwut: You've included both `jquery-ui.min.js` and `jquery-ui.js` - it probably won't affect your code, but you only need to include one of these. You'll also need to put the `jquery-1.10.2.js` reference *before* the `jquery-ui.min.js` reference.

Comment: Didn't change the result, but thanks for mentioning!

Comment: @Trollwut: Not sure if it will make any difference, but since your code is already inside a `$(function() {...})` block, you don't need the `$(document).ready(function(){` - just call the plugin directly.

Comment: Nope, it's not. :) Edited it for better readability.